# How to display image in spring boot using JSTL tag library?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I have some image located at:

```
C:\Users\AshwinPC\Desktop\vemployee\src\main\webapp\upload
```

Now I want to display images at jsp using jstl tag library.But ,I am not getting the required output.
I,tried like this :

```
<c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

        <div class="box-part text-center">

            <img src="C:\Users\AshwinPC\Desktop\vemployee\src\main\webapp\upload\'${employee.iNumber}'" />

        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Image is not being succesfully being displayed.When,I inspect then I see like this:

[image]

**i123122** is the image saved at the location in my **C:\Users\AshwinPC\Desktop\vemployee\src\main\webapp\upload.**
How to show the image?What is my mistake here?

Comment: HTML pages can't load images from the disk of the user. They can only load images from an HTTP server.

Comment: how can i solve this?

Comment: By serving the image using HTTP, and using the URL (absolute or relative) of the image in the `src` attribute.

Comment: my image are being uploaded in C:\Users\AshwinPC\Desktop\vemployee\src\main\webapp\upload